# glDrawElements works perfectly on ubuntu, but does not work on mac

Tags: opengl, vbo

I was writing a VBO program some time ago. I finished coding and got the exact result as I want, but I only get a blackscreen in the mac with the same code. My guess is that there is something wrong with glDrawElements, but I used glGetError, it returns 0, which doesn't tell me any mistakes? Anyone know why they perform so differently?

p.s. I was using sfml. I'm not sure about whether there is possibility of crashing in this part.

Comment: Maybe you'd get less of a negative responds by actually posting some minimal code. Coding is not a philosophy class, where everyone loves to make up their own story about the universe. ;)

Comment: I just found out the answer. It was so stupid that OpenGL in Mac does not support glBindAttribLocation, so after I changed to glGetAttribLocation, everything works fine...

Comment: You could add this as answer and accept it, that way the question will be marked as solved. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL in Mac does not support glBindAttribLocation, so after I changed to glGetAttribLocation, everything works fine